# How to connect to mysql docker container from flask application using sql-alchemy

Tags: mysql, docker, flask

I have a flask application. This application is running locally. I have pulled mysql:5.7 and it is running. I want to create a database inside the mysql:5.7 container from the flask application and use that. I am using sql_alchemy.

I have given the uri as

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:root@172.17.0.2:4000/document_generator'
```

where root and root are mysql username and password respectively. 172.17.0.2 is the ip address of the mysql container. I have run the container using

```
docker run  -p 4000:4000  -e MY_SQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root mysql:5.7
```

I have exposed the port 4000. But, when i get inisde the conatiner and try

```
show global variables like 'port';
```

it gave 3306 as the port.

I tried using both the ports in the SQL_ALCHEMY_URI, but none of them were able to create the database.I also tried changing mysql:// to mysql+pymsql://. Even that dint work.
I have written the table creation code inside models.py

```
class Users(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'users'
username = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=True)
password = db.Column(db.String(256), nullable=False)
private_id = db.Column(db.String(128), primary_key=True)
```

I want the database to be created in the mysql container when i run my flask application. I have no idea about docker-compose. Any help would be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Publishing port will not change the PORT in MySQL schema, if you want to connect with MySQL container using port `4000` you just need to map `4000` with `3306`.

```
docker run  -p 4000:3306  -e MY_SQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root mysql:5.7
```

Also will suggest using [docker network](https://docs.docker.com/network/) instead of IP of the container, as IP change frequently.

But still if you want to start MySQL on port `4000` you can try something like

```
docker run -it -p 4000:4000  -e MY_SQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root mysql:5.7 --port=4000
```

And then if you query like

```
show global variables like 'port';
```

You will get `4000`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `docker run` command specificities the port to be published as `4000:4000`.

The left side of the `:` is `4000` which is the port on your local machine, and that's fine.

But the right side of the `:` which is also `4000` is the port inside the container where is running MySQL. The default port of MySQL is `3306`, not `4000`, so you're trying to reach MySQL on the wrong port.

To fix that:

1. Stop the docker container

```
# Show all the running containers. The last column should be the container name.
$ docker ps

# Stop and remove the container
$ docker rm -f <container name>
```

2. Re-create the container with the right port

```
$ docker run -p 4000:3306 -e MY_SQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root mysql:5.7
```

Now it should work.

#### Bonus

Docker exposes the containers also on the localhost. You can also reach the database on `localhost:4000`.

Comment: I tried the same command, now when i run the flask application and then enter the mysql container using docker exec -it bash 1234, mysql -u root -p, and do show databases, the database is still not created!!!

Comment: `docker exec -it bash 1234` doesn't look like a valid docker command. It should be something like `docker exec -it <mysql_container_name> bash`. Anyway, have a look at the container logs, you may have a permission issue: `docker logs -f <container name>`.

Comment: Oops!! That was a typo, 1. docker exec -it <conatiner_id> bash    2. mysql -u root -p    3. show databases.      I run these commands, and still the database document_generator is not created.

Comment: `2019-12-20T08:54:52.912879Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
version: '5.7.28'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)` after this there are no logs, even though i run my flask application

Comment: Does your flask application logs anything? It should complain it can't connect I guess. Could you try to use a MySQL client software (like https://www.sequelpro.com or any other tool) to connect to MySQL to be sure all works fine on the Docker side?